# Weak vs Strong Dependency

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am working on some approximation techniques for a sequence of Bernoulli random variables. I have come across the concept of week and strong dependency. I tried to find some example of it but I couldn't since most of the definitions of dependency are abstract without any example. Does any one know what does it mean when two random variables are said to be week dependent (or strong dependent)?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In probability, weak dependence of random variables is a
>   generalization of independence that is weaker than the concept of a
>   martingale. A (time) sequence of random variables is weakly dependent
>   if distinct portions of the sequence have a covariance that
>   asymptotically decreases to 0 as the blocks are further separated in
>   time. Weak dependence primarily appears as a technical condition in
>   various probabilistic limit theorems.

-Wikipedia

So basically if we keep testing the variables over and over again and compute covariance each time, it should approach $0$.

I take strong dependence to be the opposite of weak dependence, when the covariance asymptotically converges to some finite nonzero value.

Comment: How do we prove that the definition of weak dependence applies to martingales? It is not obvious at all, and personally I am not sure it is even true in general